# sony camera remote picture orientation

Tags: camera, orientation, sony

Sony cameras change picture orientation by default.

Is there a way to set a fixed picture orientation (portrait/landscape) using the remote API?  I could not find any in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that is not possible using the Camera Remote API.